# Artifacts when viewing pdfs in Preview (and Skim)

Tags: pdf, preview, font, skim

When I view PDFs with Preview or Skim sometimes scrolling cause the following artifact

[image]

Here in 0,06 it seems as if one or two rows of pixels are cut.

If I cause the fonts to redraw by any means (getting the text out of displaying area, selecting text) the artifact disappears. I wonder where is the right place to report this bug.

Comment: Please provide information about your system.

Comment: I would report it at http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: I have the MacBook Pro with Retina display (Early 2013) with OS X 10.8.4.

Comment: I have submitted a bugreport, thank you for the link.

Answer (score 1):

The first, simplest step for troubleshooting even an Apple app that is acting up is to quit it and delete its preference files. There are some utilities that check the validity of preferences files and delete corrupt ones. Easier still is to move them to the trash from your 
User Library at ~/User/Library/Preferences 
or the Main Library at HardDisk/Library/Preferences. The application will rebuild a fresh set next time you open it.

(Note I am not referring to the Library within the System Folder.)

If there are complicated settings you might want to remember, make a sticky first!

The second step is often to download or otherwise install a fresh copy of the application itself. It's surprising what both these steps can accomplish.